# Trying to avoid correlated subquery in T-SQL for Netezza re-write - MAX(COALESCE()) not working in aggregate query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, aggregate, coalesce

Take a look at this T-SQL query.  It has a nested query.  I'm trying to make it work without the nested query in the same way.  The reason I'm doing this is because I'd like to write something similar in Netezza, but Netezza's query engine doesn't allow you to reference tables of an outer query inside a nested query.  Notice in my dummy data, I have whether it's a branch or leaf hard coded, but in my first query, I'm calculating whether it's a branch or leaf, and it comes out the same.

At the end of my question, I have my dummy data and a simple query so you can see what's there.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.[PATH],  
    F1.BRANCH_OR_LEAF,  
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT [FILE].ID)
        FROM FOLDER F2
            JOIN [FILE] ON F2.ID = [FILE].FOLDER_ID
        WHERE   
            F2.[PATH] LIKE (F1.[PATH] + '%')

    ) file_count,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN 
                MAX(COALESCE(F2.ID, -1)) != COALESCE(F1.ID, -1)
            THEN
                'B'
            ELSE
                'L'
            END AS BRANCH_OR_LEAF           
        FROM FOLDER F2
            JOIN [FILE] ON F2.ID = [FILE].FOLDER_ID
        WHERE   
            F2.[PATH] LIKE (F1.[PATH] + '%')

    ) branch_or_leaf
FROM
    [FOLDER] F1
ORDER BY 
    F1.[PATH]
```

[image]

Query where aggregate MAX(COALESCE not working:

```
SELECT
    F1.PATH AS FOLDER_PATH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) AS FILE_COUNT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) > 0 THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'H'
    END,
    (
        LEN(F1.PATH) - LEN(REPLACE(F1.PATH, '/', '')) - 1
    ) AS FOLDER_LEVEL
    --,
    --CASE
    --  WHEN MAX(coalesce(F1.ID,'-1')) != coalesce(F2.ID,'-1') THEN 'B'
    --  ELSE 'L'
    --END AS BRANCH_OR_LEAF
FROM
    [FOLDER] F1
    LEFT JOIN [FOLDER] F2 ON F2.PATH LIKE (F1.PATH + '%')
    JOIN [FILE] F ON F2.ID = F.FOLDER_ID
GROUP BY
    F1.PATH
```

When I uncomment the comment, I get this.

*Column 'FOLDER.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Here's what my current dummy data looks like.

```
SELECT F1.ID, F1.[PATH], F1.BRANCH_OR_LEAF, F.ID, F.NAME
FROM [FOLDER] F1
JOIN [dbo].[FILE] F ON F1.ID = F.FOLDER_ID
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use `coalesce(F2.ID,'-1')` without grouping by `F2.ID`. It has nothing to do with the `MAX(COALESCE`-statement.

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't throw an error, but now I get 25 rows instead of 8.  5 level 1, 5 level 2, 4 level 3, 5 level 4, 2 level 5.

Comment: That's a completely different question. You can do a sub-query first getting `MAX(coalesce(F1.ID,'-1'))` and then the outer would check if it should be ´B´ or ´L`

Comment: Since Netezza doesn't allow correlated subqueries (referencing outer table in subquery), I need to avoid subqueries.  This question is a T-SQL question, but I was trying to get ideas really.  Do you think my only other option is to build a temp table and store the max values of the descendent folders of each folder?  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html?lang=en

Comment: I've never used Netezza but if there are no subqueries then yes. If there are no CTEs like in the current answer then yes.

Comment: Just read that you can make two subqueries and then join them.

Comment: See my answer.  I'm now using a temp table, so Netezza should be able to handle it.

Comment: Asken, I probably could put the subquery in the join rather than building the temp table first.  I *think* that's legal in Netezza.  I *think*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably allow me to accomplish what I want in Netezza.  In a realistic scenario, you can't confirm that the LEN function is sufficient, but since we're already checking if one string contains the other, this should be fine.  I would use the CHECKSUM_AGG function, but Netezza doesn't use that.  So this will have to do.

```
create table #branch_or_leaf
(
    [folder_id] int,
    [path] nvarchar(50),  -- for reference purposes only
    [branch_or_leaf] [nvarchar](50)
)

INSERT INTO #branch_or_leaf
SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.ID, 
    F1.PATH,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(LEN(F2.PATH)) = LEN(F1.PATH) THEN 'L'
        ELSE 'B'
    END
FROM
    [FOLDER] F1
    LEFT JOIN [FOLDER] F2 ON F2.PATH LIKE (F1.PATH + '%') 
GROUP BY 
    F1.ID, F1.PATH

SELECT * FROM #branch_or_leaf

SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.PATH AS FOLDER_PATH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) AS FILE_COUNT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) > 0 THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'H'
    END,
    (
        LEN(F1.PATH) - LEN(REPLACE(F1.PATH, '/', '')) - 1
    ) AS FOLDER_LEVEL,
    BL.branch_or_leaf AS branch_or_leaf
FROM
    [FOLDER] F1
    LEFT JOIN [FOLDER] F2 ON F2.PATH LIKE (F1.PATH + '%')
    JOIN [FILE] F ON F2.ID = F.FOLDER_ID
    JOIN #branch_or_leaf BL ON F1.ID = BL.folder_id
GROUP BY
    F1.PATH, BL.branch_or_leaf
ORDER BY
    F1.PATH

DROP TABLE #branch_or_leaf
```

## EDIT:

Similar query, but now we have our nested query in the FROM clause.  This **might** be legal in Netezza.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT F1.PATH AS FOLDER_PATH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) AS FILE_COUNT,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT F.ID) > 0 THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'H'
    END,
    (
        LEN(F1.PATH) - LEN(REPLACE(F1.PATH, '/', '')) - 1
    ) AS FOLDER_LEVEL,
    BL.BL AS branch_or_leaf
FROM
    [FOLDER] F1
    LEFT JOIN [FOLDER] F2 ON F2.PATH LIKE (F1.PATH + '%')
    JOIN [FILE] F ON F2.ID = F.FOLDER_ID
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT F1.ID, 
            CASE 
                WHEN SUM(LEN(F2.PATH)) = LEN(F1.PATH) THEN 'L'
                ELSE 'B'
            END AS BL
        FROM
            [FOLDER] F1
            LEFT JOIN [FOLDER] F2 ON F2.PATH LIKE (F1.PATH + '%') 
        GROUP BY 
            F1.ID, F1.PATH      
    ) AS BL ON F1.ID = BL.ID
GROUP BY
    F1.PATH, BL.BL
ORDER BY
    F1.PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a table from your dummy data and I didn't even look at your query. I instead wrote my own. It's very, very close, but it seems like your dummy data is missing a row with the path "/AA/BB/CC/"

Your Query should look something like this. I assume you will switch the CTE to a subquery or temp table. But I made it a CTE for readability.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT F1.ID FolderID, F1.[PATH], F1.BRANCH_OR_LEAF, F.ID FileID, F.NAME
    FROM [FOLDER] F1
    JOIN [dbo].[FILE] F ON F1.ID = F.FOLDER_ID
)

SELECT A.[Path],A.Branch_or_Leaf,COUNT(DISTINCT B.FileID) file_Count
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN  CTE B
ON A.[Path] = LEFT(B.[Path],LEN(A.[Path]))
GROUP BY A.Path,A.Branch_or_Leaf,B.Branch_Or_Leaf
ORDER BY A.[Path]
```

Results:

```
Path                      Branch_or_Leaf file_Count
------------------------- -------------- -----------
/AA/                      B              5
/AA/                      B              8
/AA/BB/                   B              4
/AA/BB/                   B              8
/AA/BB/CC/CC.1/           L              2
/AA/BB/CC/CC.2/           B              1
/AA/BB/CC/CC.2/           B              4
/AA/BB/CC/CC.2/CC.22/     L              3
/AA/BB/CC/CC.2/CC.23/     L              4
/AA/BB/CC/DD/             L              2
```

Comment: In my [FILE] associative table, there is no file for folder '/AA/BB/CC/'.  It basically has a file count of 0.  That's why it's missing.  But since all of CC's descendents have 9 distinct files, it shows 9.  I have 13 files total, and some of those files are copied in multiple folders.  So it should only show the unique count at each level for itself and descendant folders.  Although I need it to be there.  Neat query but the file counts look off.  I'm just wondering if this will work in Netezza?

Comment: I've never heard of Netezza so I wouldn't know where to start. I think my query should be a good start for you though. All you have to do is write a query to add the missing value unless you need my help with that.

Comment: I like the fact that you're using WITH keyword.  That's nice for recursion.  IBM's product Netezza (used for data warehousing) doesn't have that.  I'm basically trying to get ideas from answers of this question to re-write my query in Netezza.  Thanks for your input.